# how can I find if a global variable or route for my views is defined in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with a project already started by other person, I found this part of code and I seriously dont know what means.

I understand :partial -> "tests/show_#{test.type}" sends to a view... in my db type is a number, so, I guess in some part it might decided depending of the number which view to get, and I am not sure if that is on :locals, in case is that, I dont know where to look for, anybody knows what does :locals mean? (i thought was a router, but it is not) and, the view it shows its a `show_questions` and the others are `show_types` and so on...(never show_1, show_2 ...) , but like i said, type brings a number.

```
= render :partial => "tests/show_#{test.type}", :locals => {:test=> test, :index => idx}
```

Any idea how to debug this to find out how it converts into name of the view?? I dont know where to look for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:locals are the local variables that you pass into the partial. 
In your example, the variables 'test' and 'index' will be accessible from the "tests/show_#{test.type}" partial.

Comment: and for example, if i have show_types but tests/show_#{test.type} prints something like tests/show_1 ... there is somewhere where translate that to show_types ?

Comment: i don't understand your question, and in general wouldn't recommend dynamically generating names for partials